# how to assign roles to users with meteor?

Tags: meteor

how to assign roles to users with meteor?
I installed the package meteor add alanning: roles, and then I went into command prompt and typed the meteor command shell to access the meteor console server side. and i typed this code:

```
Var = myId Meteor.users.findOne ({username: "Elsa"}) ._ id
Roles.addUsersToRoles (myId, [ 'admin'])**
```

to assign the right to the admin user and Elsa in Mongolia I see no added admin roles in the collection

Comment: `var user = Meteor.users.findOne({username: "Elsa"})`
Is there any user with this username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the package
https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles
Please be sure that username in database is unique.
Try these inside Meteor.startup code much before in server folder, place these

```
var id = Meteor.users.findOne({username: "Elsa"});
Roles.addUsersToRoles(id._id, ['admin'], 'default-group');
```

Hope these help